# JSON Object Request GET Method

Tags: java, android, json, jsonobjectrequest

Why i can't send parameter in url with string contain more than one word in JSON Object Request?

When i trying to send parameter with string "haha" it work, but when i trying to send parameter with string "haha haha" (with space between the words) it calls onErrorResponse function.

Below is my code :

```
String url = String.format("http://172.xx.x.xx:xxxxx/api/users?name=%s", nama);

JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
```

What the solution so my url can receive string parameter with more than one words inside the string parameter??

Comment: Please try to encode `nama` like `new URLEncoder().encode(nama, Charsets.UTF_8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String nama = "haha haha";
String url = "http://172.xx.x.xx:xxxxx/api/users?name="+nama;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this because when you send request the spacce reloaced by %20
String url = String.format("http://172.xx.x.xx:xxxxx/api/users?name=%s", nama.replace(" ","%20"));